# Using SockJS in Meteor to connect to external service or stream API

Tags: meteor, sockjs

I am trying to use SockJS from my Meteor to connect to another service but I can't get a reference to SockJS within meteor client or server. Does anyone have a good example of using SockJS to connect to other service or streaming API's from Meteor?

I have tried to accomplish this two ways but 'socket' is always undefined:

```
var socket = sockjs.createServer({ sockjs_url: 'http://api.hitbtc.com:8081' });
    socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        console.log("CONNECTED!!" + data)
    };


var socket = new SockJS('http://api.hitbtc.com:8081');
        socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
            var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            console.log("CONNECTED!!" + data)
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though SockJS is used by the Meteor itself it's [hidden deeply](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/stream_client_sockjs.js#L163) inside the `ddp` package and it's not really exposed to the users. So basically, you have two options here:

1. You can either put another copy of SockJS into your app, ...
2. ... or you can teach your custom server to understand DDP protocol, then you will be able to use `DDP.connect` to establish a new connection.

The second solution does not make sense of course if you are using 3rd party service. The first solution feels ugly because of the data redundancy, but I am afraid it's the only way out if `2.` is not acceptable.

Comment: That explains a lot.  I ended up using option #1 by adding a second copy of SockJS (sockjs-client-node) to my package and I was then able to use SockJS to connect to the 3rd party service.  Agreed this is an ugly solution, SockJS should be exposed in Meteor.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does that mean you were able to use the second instance of SockJS to talk between Meteor and the 3rd party?

Comment: Yes I was able to use the second instance of the socket library to connect Metero to the 3rd party.  You can use any socket library you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the server:

execute `Npm.require('./')` and observe the path informed in the error, from it you can point to the packages from the depths of Meteor, in the case of SockJS the path (in version 1.10.2 of Meteor) is:

```
Npm.require('./meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs');
```

In the specific case of Sockjs, its use is slightly different from that presented on the Github page, as follows:

```
const sockjs = Npm.require('./meteor/ddp-server/node_modules/sockjs');

const echo = sockjs.listen(WebApp.httpServer, {prefix: '/echo'});

echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
  conn.on ('data', function(message) {
    conn.write(message);
  });
  conn.on('close', function(){});
});
```

I didn't find the sockjs "client" package in these files, because the sockjs-client package is specific to the browser. So I downloaded from the CDN that the "echo" output provided, I use "--exclude-archs web.browser.legacy" in my test environment, but from what I read out there the sockjs-client package is available if you don't use it this parameter.
Sockjs relies on "faye-websocket" which has both a client and a websocket server designed to run on NodeJs, here is the suggestion.

Ps: I didn't find an equivalent form on the client side (there is no Npm.require)